# What power does an employer have over gratuities/tips?

Tags: canada, labor-law, british-columbia, payment

First, what is the difference between tips and a gift? Can an employer legally order employees not to accept either? Can an employer order an employee to share it? For example in restaurants many have a system where tips that are given to the servers are shared with the kitchen staff. Can a server refuse to go with the system and keep her tips for herself?

This is under the law of British Columbia.

Comment: This is essentially one question: what power does an employer have over an employee accepting things from customers. The rest is details and specifics.Iit should not be closed as lacking focus.

Answer (score 1):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

### It's undecided

There is no law in Australia on the matter of tips: no legislation, no case law, no modern awards - nothing, nada, zilch.

There is a little bit of English law from the 19th century that is probably good law in Australia and a little bit from the 20th and 21st that probably isn't because Australia's employment law diverged significantly from the UK's following Federation in 1901.

### Tipping culture in [australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

[This](https://www.moneymag.com.au/tipping-into-us-tipping-culture#:%7E:text=To%20tip%20or%20not%20to,to%20recognise%20their%20good%20service.) article by an American living in Australia gives a good overview of the current state of play of tipping.

As a native-born and bred Australian, I can anecdotally say that tipping, apart from a "keep the change" style, is a relatively recent phenomenon. Its rise is intimately linked with the Boeing 747 because that aircraft lowered the price of travel to Europe and North America to the point where most middle-class (from the 1980s) and working-class (from the 1990s) could travel and be exposed to the tipping culture there and bring it back home. At the same time, there were Europeans and North Americans travelling to Australia and bringing their tipping habits with them and, most people don't refuse a tip when it's offered even if tipping is unusual.

However, the rise in tipping culture has been offset by the [decline](https://www.rba.gov.au/publications/bulletin/2020/jun/cash-use-in-australia-results-from-the-2019-consumer-payments-survey.html) in cash payments - tipping by handing the server extra cash is easier than when using a tap-and-go electronic payment. Some outlets allow a % tip to be added to the bill but the overwhelming majority don't.

It's fair to say that tipping in restaurants and cafes with table service is appreciated but not expected and it is virtually unknown outside that sector. Australians do not routinely tip where payment for food happens in advance, taxi or Uber drivers, bartenders, hairdressers, nail artists, masseuses, doorpersons, bellhops or concierges.

Tips do not make up a large proportion of hospitality workers' income - they are paid a minimum award wage which is currently AUD 19.84 (USD 15.39) per hour plus an additional 25% if they are casual employees. Tips are a genuine gratuity - a payment made in appreciation for exceptional service; not a payment for just doing your job.

I venture to suggest that most Australians who tip expect that the tips go to the employee(s).

### Tip distribution practices

We don't really know but it's fair to say that there is a wide diversity of practice.

Gow & Frazer of the University of Wollongong produced [Who owns tips? Hospitality workers and the distribution of customer gratuities](https://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3148&context=lhapapers) in 2015 based on a tiny qualitative study of 6 restaurants, 6 cafes and 6 bars, all non-family owned, in the CBD of [Wollongong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wollongong) the 3rd largest city in New South Wales (11th largest in Australia) with a population of just over 300,000 today (about 280,000 at the time of the study in 2014). As far as they knew, there had never been any research on this before their paper.

They found that cash tips may be given directly to the server, left on the table or bar, or placed in a prominent tip jar near the till. Electronic tips naturally go into the business' bank account. The tip jar was the most common (n=11) and electronic tips were non-existent outside restaurants but common (n=5) and a significant proportion of tip revenue in those.

> Once received, tips may be appropriated by the employer/proprietor, retained by
> individual serving staff, or pooled in some fashion for distribution. Media accounts suggest that pooling of tips is normal at hospitality establishments in Australia, although it is common for the employer/proprietor to keep a portion of the pool before distribution, or else to take a share of the tip pool on distribution. All of the Wollongong establishments examined used pooling of tips. Once pooled, tips were distributed using one or a combination of the following methods:
>
> - dividing the tips evenly at the end of a shift with remaining staff (n=6);
> - dividing the tips based on hours worked on a periodical basis (n=6);
> - allocating the total amount for a staff social event, such as the Christmas party or
>   periodical dinners (n=7); and
> - retaining the tips for the business, either entirely or by percentage (n=6).
>
> The distribution systems reported by research participants ranged from simple to very
> complex. ...
>
> Research participants were asked what the correct response would be under the workplace
> tipping system if a customer directly handed an employee a $20 tip. Some hospitality enterprises permitted or encouraged employees to keep the hypothetical $20 despite the
> pooling system (n=5). The majority of hospitality enterprises required employees to contribute any tips given directly by customers into the distribution pool (n=13). The research participants were also asked whether they would pool the tip or keep the tip in this situation. Of the 13 establishments that required employees to pool direct tips, five research participants responded that they would keep the tip in breach of the ‘rule’. Many respondents pointed out that the direct and personal nature of the tip made them feel they ‘earned’ the money.

There was also evidence that some employers withheld tips as a disciplinary measure.

### So, legally, who owns the tip?

A tip has the legal status of a gift since it is not a contractually obligated payment. That is, once offered and accepted title passes from the giver to the recipient. However, most tips are anonymous and there is no clear indication from the giver who the intended recipient is. Is it the business? The individual server? All the servers collectively? All the employees collectively including back-of-house?

**We don't know.**

Judgements from 19th century England set a clear precedent that an employee has a well-recognised duty to account to their employer for all property acquired in the course of their employment. This is a duty in both common law and equity and does not depend on the existence of fiduciary duties. For example, in *Morison* (1874) LR 9 QB 480 at 483:

> the profits acquired by the servant or agent in the course of, or in connection with, his service or agency, belonging to the master or principal.

So, that's clear then. The employer owns the tips, right? Well ...

Around the turn of the 20th century, the UK imported the [tronc](https://www.mercerhole.co.uk/insights/what-is-the-tronc-system/) system where tips for servants in seaside resorts, who were initially independent contractors rather than employees, were pooled and then distributed by one or more of those servants who were entrusted with the task by the others. As these servants became employees of the hotels and resorts, the tronc system was maintained largely without management involvement.

The practice was considered by the English Court of Appeal in *Wrottesley v Regent Street Florida Restaurant* [1951] 2 KB 277 who held that the tips were not 'wages' and that the employer never held title to them even though they were in his custody. However, the court *assumed* this state of affairs - they didn't actually *rule* it - they implied a trust prospectively without actually finding that a constructive trust had actually been established. This state of affairs was also *assumed* in *Annabel’s (Berkeley Square) Ltd v Revenue and Customs Commissioners* [2009] 4 All ER 55; [2009] ICR 1123; [2009] STC 1551; [2009] EWCA Civ 361.

So, that's clear. The tips belong to the employees. Well, ...

The tronc system never happened in Australia so it's unclear if this finding (which \doesn't actually find anything - it assumes a state of affairs) would apply. On the one hand, it seems similar to the tip pooling that usually happens but the employer is more intimately involved than they are with the tronc in the UK.

There are two English cases (*Penn v Spiers & Pond Ltd* [1908] 1 KB 766; (1908) 1 BWCC 401; *Great Western Railway Co v Helps* [1918] AC 141) that found that when tips are handed directly to an employee, the money belongs to the employee:

> In both cases the court found that where the giving and receiving of tips is ‘open and notorious … [and] sanctioned by the employer’, a term was implied in the contract that employees were allowed to retain tips.

However, in *Nerva v RL & G Ltd* [1997] ICR 11 the court found that when tips were paid by cheque or credit card they became the property of the business. However, a dissenting opinion held that while legal title passed to the employer, they were acting as an agent of the customer and had a duty to fulfil the customer's wishes that the money goes to the employees.

It's worth noting that all of the 20th and 21st-century disputes above were not between the employer and employee over ownership of the tips directly but about matters such as whether tips could be counted as part of the minimum wage, are subject to insurances levied on wages and other indirect matters. That is, they were not about who owned the tip, but what effect the payment of the tip had on other workplace obligations.

### Australian Law

**Implied terms**

While the English terms above are implied by law (and there are no such precedents in Australia), terms can also be implied in Australia by:

- industry custom but only if it is ‘necessary for the reasonable or effective operation of a contract of that nature in the circumstances of the case’ (*Hawkins v Clayton* (1988) 164 CLR 539 at 573, Deane J; 78 ALR 69; [1988] HCA 15; BC8802597) - it's hard to see how a term about ownership of tips is necessary for an employment contract that works perfectly well without dealing with tips.
- Terms have been implied at an individual workplace level on matters including reasonable overtime, Sunday penalty rates, taxi provision and flexi-days - if a business has a consistently applied tipping regime, then that may be an implied term of the employment contract but only for that workplace.

**Awards**

There are four modern awards relevant to employees who receive tips (Hospitality Industry (General) Award 2010 [MA000009]; Registered and Licensed Clubs Award 2020 [MA000058]; Restaurant Industry Award 2010 [MA000119]; Fast Food Industry Award 2010 [MA000003]). None of these have any provision concerning tips.

**Enterprise agreements**

> Enterprise agreements may only contain content which deals with matters pertaining to the relationship between the employer and employees who are covered by the agreement.  On one view, tips clearly have a direct impact on employer-employee relations. ...
>
> On another view, tips potentially fall beyond matters pertaining to the employment relationship due to the role of the customer as a party in the transaction.

The second approach is indirectly supported by a 2003 application for an Enterprise Agreement:

> The employer argued that, because they recognised employees’ entitlement to tips, this benefit could be taken into account under the former ‘no disadvantage’ test'. Watson SDP rejected this contention, stating that ‘employees are entitled to retain gratuities. The agreement provides no benefit in this regard’.

However, the Fair Work Commission is an administrative tribunal, not a court, so its decisions do not set precedent. Since this decision was not appealed ...

**Unauthorised deductions**

Section 323 of the Fair Work Act requires employees to be paid in full, in money, and at least monthly. If tips are wages or entitlements, then they cannot be withheld to pay for breakages or till shortfalls, be paid in other than money (as social events would be), or paid 3 monthly as some respondents reported.

Alternatively, if they are not and they are the employee's property held by the employer on trust or as agent for the customer, then the employer cannot appropriate them either.

**Consumer law**

> The Australian Consumer Law provides potential rights and remedies for customers and employees. It is a tenable proposition that most customers assume that the tips they provide will be distributed to staff members at some point. When employers retain tips in whole or in part, or when tips go to a staff social event, a breach of the Australian Consumer Law may occur. For example, a distribution contrary to an express statement or implication made to a customer would breach the misleading or deceptive conduct provision.

> There is a second provision in the Australian Consumer Law which may be used by
> employees. Section 31 prohibits conduct liable to mislead persons seeking employment as to ‘the availability, nature, terms or conditions of the employment; or any other matter relating to the employment’. This still
> may have application as in some hospitality establishments tips are a significant proportion of income and may be a decisive factor in choosing to accept employment. This provision is beneficial to aggrieved employees as it relates directly to employment, and is an offence of absolute liability with criminal provisions.

**Tax**

The Australian Tax Office is quite clear that whoever ultimately receives the tip owes income tax on it. There is a legal onus on the taxpayer to declare them and remit the taxes. If tips *are* wages or entitlements, then there would be an onus on the employer to withhold tax and remit it on behalf of the employee. In practice, cash tips probably go missing from tax reporting.

Similarly, if tips are wages then they would be subject to state payroll taxes and other wage overheads like workers compensation premiums. It would follow that injured workers should be able to claim them under workers compensation.

They would not be subject to Goods and Services Tax because, being voluntarily, they are not payment for goods or services.

Answer (score -1):

> what is the difference between tips and a gift?

*Tip* suggests a context services provided, where a customer feels satisfied enough to voluntarily give some extra compensation to the employee(s) who provided the service. See the definition of *gratuity* in  the [BC Employment Standards Act](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/96113_01#section1). The term *gift* is more general in that it does not need to involve a context of employment/services. A gift can be made before a service is provided or without a service being --or expected to be-- provided at all. The Act does not even define or use the notion of *gift* in a way distinguishable from *gratuities*.

> Can an employer legally order employees not to accept either?

No. [Section 30.3(c) of the Act](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/96113_01#section30.3) prohibits the employer to "*require an employee to return or give the employee's gratuities to the employer*". Employer's order not to accept gratuities is equivalent to requiring the employee to return them.  However, section 30.4 provides an exception which relates to your next question.

> Can an employer order an employee to share it?

Yes, provided that "*the employer collects and redistributes gratuities among some or all of the employer's employees*". See section 30.4.

The statute allows the employer to *share in* gratuities "*if the employer regularly performs to a substantial degree the same work provided by (a) some or all of the employees who share in the redistribution, or (b) employees of other employers in the same industry who commonly receive or share in gratuities*".

> someone was fired when he said "yes" when a customer asked if he would like a hat.

That is in violation of sections 30.3 and 30.4. The manager's bare story does not relfect elements which would render that policy, let alone the decision to terminate the employee, permissible.

Comment: Why "_Employer's order not to accept gratuities is equivalent to requiring the employee to return them_"?

Comment: @Greendrake Because both requirements have the same effect: To deprive the employee of a tangible asset that customers intended to give to the employee. By rejecting gratuities, the employee is returning them instantaneously. The fact that in a scenario of rejection the asset might not yet have been physically released from customer's hand makes no difference from a legal standpoint.

Comment: Secs 30.3 & 30.4 say  "returning gratuities **to the employer**" or giving them to the employer. They do **not** speak of returning them **to the customer** nor of requiring the employee **not to accept** gratuities. I would like to see some source for your equation of the statute rule with "refusal to accept".  If gratuities are returned to the employer, then presumably the employer retains them and directly benefits. If they are returned to the customer or refused, the customer retains them. That seems a significant difference, legally. Can store be advertised as "no-tip" and this enforced?

Comment: https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/new-bc-tip-legislation-1.5116237 says this law was passed in response to employers retaining a share of tips, or confiscating them as a disciplinary measure, not to enforced no-tip status

Comment: several news stories such as https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/no-tip-restaurants-fight-to-gain-traction-1.2640476 and https://www.ctvnews.ca/canada/vancouver-restaurant-abandons-no-tipping-policy-higher-wages-1.2987217 discuss problems employers have with no-tip rules, but do not mention legal issues, some places seem to persist with such rules

Comment: @DavidSiegel "*Secs 30.3 & 30.4 say "returning gratuities **to the employer**" or giving them to the employer*". No, don't alter the statute. There is no "*to the employer*" between the statutory terms "*return*" and "*or give*". The clause "*to the employer*" encompasses only "*or give*". The Cambridge Dictionary defines [return](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/return) as "*to send, take, give, put, etc. something **back to where it came from***" (emphasis added). A tip comes from the customer, not from the employer. Therefore, a tip can be *returned* only to the customer.

Comment: @DavidSiegel "*If they are returned to the customer or refused, the customer retains them*". That protocol is neither necessary nor statutorily required. The statutory definition of *gratuity* includes the unequivocal language "***voluntarily** made to or left for an employee by a customer*" (emphasis added). This means that customer's intent beforehand is that the employee retain the tip. No need for employer's request for subsequent confirmations from the customer. The fact that news stories make no mention of legal issues is irrelevant to the question of what the law provides.

Comment: The "to the employer" part was probably intended for "return" as well, even though ambiguity indeed arises. It's in the same context as the return of wages to the employer, since the employer often receives tips on employees' behalf and remits them. Ontario's [interpretation manual](https://www.ontario.ca/document/employment-standard-act-policy-and-interpretation-manual/part-v1-employee-tips-and-other-gratuities), though legal nonbinding, supports this interpretation of a substantially same provision in Ontario.

Comment: @xngtng "*The "to the employer" part was probably intended for "return" as well*". If that were the legislative intent, the legislator could simply omit the term "return" as redundant, or use a term of which the meaning does not restrict the origin or source of payment. "*It's in the same context as the return of wages to the employer*". It is not the same. Wages come from the employer only (see "*salaries, commissions or money, paid or payable by an employer*"), and therefore only to him wages can be returned. Furthermore, the statutory definition of *wages* explicitly excludes *gratuities*.

Comment: There's a difference between employees receiving direct tips and employer receiving on behalf of employees, in which case the employer is the direct source of payment. At least one BCEST decision, in obiter, also appeared to interpret the provision this way https://canlii.ca/t/jd6nb. I'm not saying there is no ambiguity, but it is not as certain as you present it, until a court or EST decides so.

Comment: -1 Contains statements unsupported by sources.

Comment: @xngtng "*employer receiving on behalf of employees, in which case the employer is the direct source of payment*". The statutory definitions make no distinction of who is the immediate or direct source. Accordingly, only the *ultimate* source matters, and all that the Act says in this regard is that wages are paid *by* the employer and gratuities are paid *by* the customer. *Return* in a scenario of employer receiving tips on behalf of employees (1) leads to the dubious picture of money going back-and-forth between employer and employee, and (2) leaves out scenarios of direct tipping.

Comment: "leads to the dubious picture of money going back-and-forth between employer and employee" exactly why it is prohibited.  "(2) leaves out scenarios of direct tipping" exactly why return and give are both used to cover all scenarios. Your proposed interpretation might be reasonable, but the governments of the two provinces using the particular expressions do not appear to support it.

Comment: @xngtng My point is that the Act prohibits methods of deprivation of tips: One (return) relates to employee's having to tell the customer "*I can't accept tips*"; the other (give to the employer) consists of the tips being confiscated by the employer. "*the governments of the two provinces using the particular expressions do not appear to support it*". In the *RAN* matter the EST delves in the issue of whether it is lawful to include managers in a redistribution of tips, not an analysis of legislative intent behind "*return*" and "*give*". The Ontario's manual is not even issued by a tribunal.

Comment: Point being the wording by BCEST and Ontario ESP both suggest it is possible to interpret the provision to mean "return to the employer". There was no mention of the intent to ban "return to customers" in neither province's legislative debates.

Comment: In Ontario's case, the legislative intent is even more clear in the French version ("... ni contraindre l’employé à les lui retourner ou remettre ..."). The indirect object pronoun "lui", which can only mean the employer in the antecedent, is directly linked to the verb "retourner" (return).

Comment: @xngtng That's a good observation. It illustrates a problem that can arise with multilingual legislation, in part because the French version appears to suppress a key element of the commonplace meaning (and definition, as is the case with the Cambridge dictionary and elsewhere) of "return" without properly giving a statutory definition of the term. The legislator could have avoided the ambiguity as I outlined in my first reply to you. For instance, "*to transfer*" or leaving it at "*to give*" would have been more appropriate.